# jQuery removing text

Tags: jquery, html

I have this element, and the span contains a click event which cannot be deleted. I want to change the text in the A element without touching the span element.

```
<a href="#">
    <span>X</span>
    Show location
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('a').contents()[1].nodeValue="new value";
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the text you want to change in a separate SPAN-Element and change this. Accessing the A-Tag directly you will always have to care about the SPAN-Tag.